# TinyIoC inject model to class constructor

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I use TinyIoc at xamarin project, I can change IoC container, if would be necessary. How can I solve this situation?

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<IService, Service>();
        TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<ViewModel>();
        Model model; //From database... How I can inject this to my viewmodel?
        var viewModel = TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<ViewModel>();
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

internal interface IService
{
    string SomeMethod(Model model);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public string SomeMethod(Model model)
    {
        //...
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

internal class ViewModel
{
    private readonly Model model;
    private readonly IService service;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel(IService service, Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.service = service;
        this.Name = this.service.SomeMethod(this.model);
    }
}
```

the only thing I came up with is:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<IService, Service>();
        TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<ViewModel>();
        Model model; //From database... How I can inject this to my viewmodel?
        var viewModel = TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<ViewModel>();
        viewModel.Initialize(model);
    }
}

internal class ViewModel
{
    private Model model;
    private readonly IService service;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void Initialize(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.Name = this.service.SomeMethod(this.model);
    }
}
```

But I do not really like this :-( I have a bad design? Should be used dependecy injection instead of construktor injection? Or another contrainer can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the overloaded methods with Func's to see which one suits the best as I don't know how TinyIoC handles registering the actual implementation. Something like this might work:

```
.Register<ViewModel>(() => new ViewModel(
    TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IService>(), 
    model));
```

or just passing a new instance of the service:

```
.Register<ViewModel>(() => new ViewModel(new Service(), model));
```

If TinyIoC doesn't fit the bill then you could look at XLabs.IoC for alternatives that are Xamarin compatible: http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=xlabs.ioc